# How to see the version of the TAP file

Tags: unix, telecommunication, tap

This is a telecom based query.
we receive TAP files from the clearing house.
i want see on unix which version of TAP does it belong.
how can i do it.Isthere any tool to find the TAP file version?

Answer (score 0):

Try  [tap3Editor](http://www.tap3edit.com/en_1_2_what_is_tap3edit.html) its very easy to use as well do lots of other features apart from printing the version of the tap files.